# Understanding what happens within function loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to know why the inner for loop executes. My understanding is that since `j = 1` and `i = 0, j <= i;` would produce nothing as `j` is already greater than `i`. Therefore, the inner loop would be skipped, producing the same result as the initial array.

```
void sortArray(int myArray[], int size)
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int first = 0;

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (myArray[j] > myArray[first])
            {
                first = j;
            }

            temp = myArray[first];
            myArray[first] = myArray[i];
            myArray[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your inner `j` loop will be skipped on the first iteration of the `i` loop. But then it will not be when on the second iteration of the `i` loop when `i` is 1 or over.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is skipped during first iteration. After `i` is incremented, `j` is now equal to `i`, therefore the inner loop will execute 1 time. Inner loop exits, outer loop increments `i` by `1`, inner loop now iterates twice as `i == 2`.
This will repeat until `i == size - 1` OR `i < size` (same condition, different wording).

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop should skip for 1 iteration of the outer loop then will run for 1 time as `j<=i` returns `true`. (first iteration `i=0`, second iteration `i=1`)

this is equivalent to:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 0; j++)
```

After that the second loop will run 1 time equivalent to

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 1; j++)
```

and so on..

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
```